# Android: is there a simple app/widget/option to display silent/vibrate/normal

Tags: android

I recently moved to an Android phone. And now I keep missing calls because if there is an indication that I have switched my phone to silent, it is too subtle to ever notice in a sea of colour trying to grab my attention. I have enough things to remember in life without remembering I switched my phone to silent at last night's movie, or during this morning's meeting.

It would really be helpful if, instead of being a transparent (non-existant?) window through to the background wallpaper/image, the entire area behind all those tiny notifications were coloured in solid red, or orange, or some colour of my choosing to reflect the important state of my phone. To me, knowing my phone is on silent or vibrate is about the most important state to display really clearly with an obvious band of colour.

Is there such an app/widget/option? Would someone like to create one in the few minutes it should take, or better, inject it into Android itself?

Comment: There is an icon for that in the navigation bar by default. Not really obtrusive, though, but always shows when you put your device to silent mode.

Comment: That's precisely the problem, not the solution :-)

Comment: Thought so (it's too small for you). But it's the only thing I know for that – unless you're willing to invest some time and maybe a little money. A solution would be possible to construct using e.g. *Tasker* to replace your wallpaper (or place a big red icon, or whatever) whenever the device is in silent mode. *Tasker* can do that (but costs about 5 bucks), maybe some other [automation app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation#group_517) is capable of that as well (I could imagine *Llama* or *MacroDroid*, which both come for free, but cannot say for sure).

Comment: thats actually a good idea, like when you turn off data and it switches your wallpaper to 'your data is off' or something. i wonder why i havent thought of that yet even when i know i have terrible memory -.-'